# Visual Studio for Mac - No Matching Provisioning Profile

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin.ios, provisioning-profile, visual-studio-mac

The Visual Studio for Mac was working perfectly till Yesterday for my both simulator and device builds. But, today I have downloaded and installed a new provision profile with some new capabilities, after that it couldn't identify my provisioning profile even the previous one with old capabilities.

I have double checked the bundle identifier name, but no issue with bundler identifier.

The same profile is working perfectly with xcode.

I have tried development and distribution profile, but no luck.

[image]

**Edit**

I have created a new user on my macbook and opened the same project in Visual Studio, now I am able to choose the provisioning profile. It looks like there is some problem in the Visual Studio configuration in my primary user account.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61745158/visual-studio-for-mac-cannot-select-provisioning-profile.